# Do nearby allied champions of nidalee gain exp if they are lower lvl than her?

Tags: league-of-legends

If a nidalee is a higher than the nearby allied champions, does the nearby allied champion get free exp for essentially not doing anything?

Answer (score 3):

They sure do! At a rate of 5xp per 5seconds. Not super-helpful, but absolutely true.

This was on Episode 3 of the YouTube series "Rift Myths":